# Mysql service stop suddenly in VPSMysql

Tags: mysql, centos6, vps, vestacp

need your help to identify whats going on in my VPS.

I provide this mysqld.log to help us examine the problems..

```
180420 22:42:06 [Warning] IP address '{HIDDEN IP}' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
180421 13:16:56 [Warning] IP address '{HIDDEN IP}' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180421 13:56:50 [Warning] IP address '{HIDDEN IP}' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution
180421 16:51:59 [Warning] IP address '{HIDDEN IP}' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
180422  0:23:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180422  0:23:27 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 497273580
180422  0:23:27  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 497274894
180422  0:23:28  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
180422  0:23:30  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180422  0:23:31 InnoDB: 5.5.55 started; log sequence number 497274894
180422  0:23:31 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
180422  0:23:31 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
180422  0:23:31 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
180422  0:23:33 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
180422  0:23:33 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.55'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
180422  0:23:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180422  0:23:37 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 497274894
180422  0:23:37  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 497279312
180422  0:23:38  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
180422  0:23:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180422  0:23:39 InnoDB: 5.5.55 started; log sequence number 497279312
180422  0:23:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
180422  0:23:39 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
180422  0:23:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
180422  0:23:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
180422  0:23:39 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.55'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
180422  0:23:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180422  0:23:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180422  0:23:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180422  0:23:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180422  0:23:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180422  0:23:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180422  0:23:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180423 21:58:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180423 21:58:08 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 497279312
180423 21:58:08  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 497280150
180423 21:58:08  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
180423 21:58:09  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180423 21:58:10 InnoDB: 5.5.55 started; log sequence number 497280150
180423 21:58:10 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
180423 21:58:10 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
180423 21:58:10 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
180423 21:58:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
180423 21:58:10 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.55'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

This is my specification:

```
Mysql version 5.5.55
CPU Cores count 2
Total CPU(s) speed 2400Mhz
Memory 1 GB
Centos 6 32 bit
using Vesta CP
```

From logs above, whats wrong with my VPS, mysql always stop suddenly, how to automatically start mysql service after that ?

Any help will appreciate, thanks.

Comment: did you check server uptime when this event occurs may be your vps itself is restarting, also have you configured your my.cnf within the memory limits

Comment: how can I do that ? And also, Im not configured anything, so its set to default from beginning @VijayMuddu

Comment: you can run *uptime* command on the server whenever your mysql stops, uptime will show since how many hours/days the server is up

Comment: 05:41:35 up  7:43,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
@VijayMuddu

Comment: as per your uptime status your server is up from last 7:43 hours had you restarted or started your server 7:43 hours back

Comment: im not restarting my vps back then... or maybe force restart ? then what should I check ? @VijayMuddu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76498/discussion-between-vijay-muddu-and-nasihun-amin-suhardiyan).